# SwiftUI - HStack not filling space without explicit height declaration

Tags: swift, swiftui, hstack

I have the following HStack:

```
HStack(spacing: Constants.hStackSpacing) {
            if let data = viewModel.carousel {
                TitleCard(viewModel: .init(data: data, homepageTracker: viewModel.homepageTracker))
            }

            ForEach(viewModel.products, id: \.self) { product in
                ProductCard(viewModel: .init(
                    product: product,
                    imageWidth: Constants.productImageWidth))
                .onTapGesture {
                    viewModel.productCardTapped(product: product)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.leading)
```

Now, both the `TitleCard` and the `ProductCard` have explicit heights declared within them.

TitleCard:

```
struct Constants {
        static let width: CGFloat = 152
        static let height: CGFloat = 227
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            mainStack
                .frame(width: Constants.width, height: Constants.height)
            shopLabel
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            viewModel.cardTapped()
        }
    }
```

ProductCard:

```
struct Constants {
        static let productImageWidth: CGFloat = 151.5
        static let productImageHeight: CGFloat = 202
    }

@ViewBuilder private var card: some View {
        if let productImage = viewModel.productImage {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                Image(uiImage: productImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: Constants.productImageWidth, height: Constants.productImageHeight)
                    .scaledToFit()

                if let designer = viewModel.designer {
                    Spacer()

                    Text(designer)
                        .font(SwiftUI.Font((Style.font(.sansSerifBold14))))

                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, the HStack takes up no space when positioned within a VStack of another view, unless I give it a specific height, which I don't want to do. Wondering what I am doing wrong here.

Edit:

Full main view:

```
struct MainView: View {
    struct Constants {
        static let productImageWidth: CGFloat = 162
        static let hStackSpacing: CGFloat = 12.5
    }

    @StateObject var viewModel: MainViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack(spacing: Constants.hStackSpacing) {
                ForEach(viewModel.products, id: \.self) { product in
                    ProductCard(viewModel: .init(
                        product: product,
                        imageWidth: Constants.productImageWidth))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        viewModel.productCardTapped(product: product)
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.leading)
        .trackableScrollView(
            axis: .horizontal,
            closeToEndBuffer: 50,
            didInteract: { _ in
                viewModel.userDidInteract()
            }, didReachEnd: {
                viewModel.userDidReachEnd()
            })
    }
}
```

Product card:

```
struct ProductCard: View {
    struct Constants {
        static let productImageWidth: CGFloat = 151.5
        static let productImageHeight: CGFloat = 202
    }

    @StateObject var viewModel: ProductCardViewModel
    @State var productImage = UIImage()

    var body: some View {
        card
    }

    @ViewBuilder private var card: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            if let productImage = viewModel.productImage {
                Image(uiImage: productImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: Constants.productImageWidth, height: Constants.productImageHeight)
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .transition(.opacity.animation(.default))
            } else {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.clear)
                    .frame(width: Constants.productImageWidth, height: Constants.productImageHeight)
            }

            if let designer = viewModel.designer {
                Spacer()

                Text(designer)
                    .font(SwiftUI.Font((Style.font(.sansSerifBold14))))

                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am adding this to a UIKit view via UIHostingController:

```
let mainVC = UIHostingController(rootView: MainView(viewModel: .init(service: .init())))

self.addViewToContentStackView(view: mainVC.view, stackIndex: 2, parentItemOrder: parentItem.sortedOrder)
```

`addViewToContentStackView` method:

```
   private func addViewToContentStackView(view: UIView, stackIndex: Int, parentItemOrder: Int) {
        if self.contentStackView.arrangedSubviews.contains(view) == false {
            var finalStackIndex = stackIndex
            if stackIndex > self.contentStackView.arrangedSubviews.count {
                finalStackIndex = self.contentStackView.arrangedSubviews.count
            }
            self.contentStackView.insertArrangedSubview(view, at: min(parentItemOrder, finalStackIndex))
        } else { // Check if the index at which the item is present is correct
            let index = self.contentStackView.arrangedSubviews.firstIndex(of: view)
            var finalStackIndex = stackIndex
            if stackIndex > self.contentStackView.arrangedSubviews.count {
                finalStackIndex = self.contentStackView.arrangedSubviews.count
            }
            let actualIndex = min(parentItemOrder, finalStackIndex)
            if index != actualIndex {
                self.contentStackView.removeArrangedSubview(view)
                self.contentStackView.insertArrangedSubview(view, at: actualIndex)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `Spacer()` in the HStack?

Comment: It's the height that is the issue - it's like it takes up no height at all

Comment: Ok Can you show all the code here? So I can check test it. It seems some code are missing here.

Comment: is it showing any specific error? because something is missing in the code you posted here.

Comment: Added more code - I've removed the `TitleCard` just to simplify.

Comment: Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: So in order to help you, we'd need to take your code, run it (say) in Playground or some dummy app, and see what's wrong. With that much code, we'd need too much time to get it to run. So please, instead of actual code, distill your problem into smaller example with: here's the code, here's how it looks, here's how I want it to look. Then we can suggest something

Comment: But yea, very first thing to try in any case is `frame(maxHeight: .infinity)` on either HStack, or the VStack inside it, or both